# PHP JSON to Java not parsing due to invisible characters

Tags: java, php, android, json, encode

I am returning some SQL results from PHP to android.

I encode the JSON response as follows:

```
$json_string = json_encode($rows);
$json_string = str_replace("\\", "", $json_string, $i);
return $json_string;
```

Once i echo this back to android i get a string which when I place into a JSON validator gives valid JSON code.

HOWEVER....once i try to pass this valid string into a new JSONObject or JSONArray I receive an error that it cannot be converted.

I am sure that this is because of whitespace invisible characters.

I have encoded both my PHP and Java in utf-8 character set using the following in Java...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
```

and for PHP...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

but this has not solved the problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you manipulate a valid json representaion with

> ```
> $json_string = str_replace("\\", "", $json_string, $i);
> ```

Don't do that, json_encode already produces a valid json.

And the `Content-Type` should be `application/json` for only json output.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply but I have made the changes you suggest and the valid JSON string will still not convert to a JSONArray or Object

Comment: :) i mean the json string that you say is *valid*

Comment: im not sure what you mean. the string is valid as i have copy and pasted it into jsonlint to check it. for some reason though it will not accept it in JSONArray()

Comment: i mean f.ex. `{"a":1,"b":2}` is a valid json string. update your question to contain the samples you tried to feed `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`

Comment: @EHarpham : As pozs says, paste the JSON string that you are working with so we can see it. Also, post the code that you're using to parse the string and the logcat error showing where it's failing.